# DIV with Nested UL LI UL LI not expanding with clear:both

Tags: html, css, background-color, nested-lists

At the site below I'm working on a dropdown menu that will encompass quite a few sub menu items. (I currently have the display:none turned off so you can see what's going on easily.

```
http://69.195.124.59/~oldcrowe/heritage-livestock/
```

Basically what I need is the .sub-menu-wrap to cover all of the background of the nested list elements for the purpose of a background color or background image to cover the entire list. The problem is that it appears to only expand to its current ul instead of the entire nested list.

I've tried, as you can see the clear:both method to no avail. Any ideas will be so appreciated. I'm leaving out the code and css as it is quite a bit, I figure you guys will be good with the web link. If not, let me know. THANKS!

Comment: Can you provide some of the html and css? At least for the menu?

Comment: I prefer an image of how you want it to be.

Comment: Sorry but I can't post the actual html because it is full of links and apparently I don't have enough "reputation points" to post that many links. Would you mind using the link and using firebug or something of that sort? Sorry

Comment: Sorry, but I can't post images either unless I have 10 rep points! Right now the dropdown box is "stepped" just imagine it a solid rectangle, if you can help me get there the rest should be gravy. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would rather put a background on each "li" instead to try to do this.

Else you could (once the little menu expanded) use only "divs" and "p" so you can easily manipulate all this.

Comment: The problem is I want a full rectangular background to encompass the entire large dropdown, without the staggered effect. I would like to use divs, but this is wordpress and I really don't have time to restructure the menu system to include all the nice features that wp builds in. Thanks though, I may have to end up doing the li backgrounds if I can't work it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have too much floats, absolute positions, divs between ul and li...

Firstly I will make a div with margin-left and right auto and a fixed width to exclusively center the content and make de shadow border. The body tag with the gradient and an extra div with the pattern. Then you can ignore positioning of content elements.

With the menu, I've made some changes but don't keep track, use some diff tool and take an idea.

html: http://pastebin.com/RaUaKkJj (expires in 1 month)

css: http://pastebin.com/LnXYCVaZ (expires in 1 month)

screenshot: http://i41.tinypic.com/2639cuc.png (to remove: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071106075333AARtIqt )

I prefer using backgraound of ul submenu and remove div sub-menu-wraps. But I've made changes inside firebug and doesn't care about remove tags.

It needs more work with z-indexs and positioning of another elements. But it's a starting step.

Comment: thanks for the help Siot. I have stripped down the code to remove all the ul li and go with simply divs and <a>. Hopefully between your updates and the simplification things will now work!